# mysql: combine two tables that have NOTHING to do with each other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have one table:

```
**blog_posts**
id
title
desc
post
```

And a completely different table, that has nothing to do with the first table:

```
**devices**
id
brand
model
desc
price
```

I'm working on a search page, and I need users to be able to search, and get results from both tables.

How would I make write a query to get info from ALL fields?

Comment: What columns do you want the users to choose from?  And why not have two lists?  One list for blog posts and devices seems as if it might be confusing to users.

Comment: Sorry downvoted, see my answer below. Such requirement is wrong in it's root. You shouldn't mix cats with toasters or devices with blog_posts. You need to differentiate your search widget somehow or see how these tables relate (maybe not directly).

Comment: @DarkSide I disagree - a unified search widget on a page would require something just like this. I did this for a dashboard type application; the user could type anything in the search box at the top and the autocomplete & search would present them with items from a variety of sources.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm aiming for!

Comment: But such type of search (with union all) will take ages to select records if you have tables with a lot of data ... I'm not sure this is best solution for search widget, even for so called "quicksearch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you would select from both tables is to use `union all`:

```
select id, title, desc, post,
       NULL as device_id, null as brand, null as model, null as device_desc, null as price
from blog_posts
union all
select NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, id, brand, model, desc , price
from devices;
```

Comment: what does the NULL/null do in the query?

Comment: The `NULL` values are place holders.  In most databases, tables/subqueries combines with `union`/`union all` need to have the same columns.

Comment: thank you... I just needed a push in the right direction and this is perfect!

Comment: was wondering, is there a way to combine brand and model? I know about concatenating two fields, but is there a way I can pull off a `CONCACT(brand, ' ', model) as title` or something similar in this query?

Comment: You would just replace the second `NULL` in the second subquery with `CONCAT(brand, ' ', model)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE `__` = 'searchparameter'
UNION
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE `__` = 'searchparameter'
```

**CONDITION:**  Both table should have same number of column OR select same number of column from both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best to look at something like Elastic Search for a proper solution.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Answer (score -1):

This requirement is wrong. Of course you can use `UNION ALL` and stuff like that to somehow "merge" these tables, but that's absolute wrong. What will be result - devices or blog_posts or ... what?